# Could default method of an interface be used to describe a behaviour?

Tags: java, interface

Could a default method of an interface be used to describe a behaviour/scenario? I mean to describe an order of method calls. 
Simple example:

```java
public interface ExportService {
    Order getOrder(long id);
    void validateOrder(Order order);
    void processOrder(Order order);
    void processException(e);

    //is this bad? 
    default void executeOrder(long id) {
        try {
            Order order = getOrder(id);
            validateOrder(order);
            processOrder(order);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any links or best practice would be great! 
Thanks

In that case, is it more correct:

```java
public interface ExportService {
    Order getOrder(long id);
    void validateOrder(Order order);
    void processOrder(Order order);
    void processException(e);
}

public abstract class AbstractExportService implements ExportService {
    public abstract Order getOrder(long id);
    public abstract void validateOrder(Order order);
    public abstract void processOrder(Order order);
    public abstract void processException(e);

    protected void executeOrder(long id) {
        try {
            Order order = getOrder(id);
            validateOrder(order);
            processOrder(order);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass ExportService as a parameter instead of implementing each method in your abstract class and then implements ExportService in another class. Correct me if I'm wrong but this seems to be close to the Bridge design pattern.

Comment: Since you’re interested in best practices, you should almost never write `catch (Exception e)`.  RuntimeExceptions usually indicate programmer errors, so catching them is not helpful to anyone.  If your code is throwing, for example, a NullPointerException, you *want your program to fail* so you will be forced, or at least encouraged, to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct order of method calls should be described in the Javadoc of the interface and the Javadoc of the methods. That's where the users of your interface should go to learn the contract of your interface.

Defining a `default` method that is just an example of the usage of the other methods is pointless. It makes no sense to add a method to your interface if classes that implement the interface are never expected to implement it.

Besides, that `default` method cannot force users of your interface to use the other methods in the desired order. Describing the correct usage of your interface in the Javadoc also doesn't force users of your interface to use the interface correctly, but if they don't follow the contract, they shouldn't be surprised if the interface doesn't work as expected.

Comment: In that case, is it more correct? :
```
public abstract class AbstractExportService implements ExportService {
    public abstract Order getOrder(long id);
    public abstract void validateOrder(Order order);
    public abstract void processOrder(Order order);
    public abstract void processException(e);
    
    protected void executeOrder(long id) {
        try {
            Order order = getOrder(id);
            validateOrder(order);
            processOrder(order);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cdeneuve are the users of the interface (or the abstract class version) expected to use just the `executeOrder` method, or should they also call the other methods directly?

Comment: I'd expect them to only use ```executeOrder```. I need the Interface to have different sources of data and (depends of a source) different type of processing orders. Also I want somehow to define an "order processing scenario" which is independent from order's source

Comment: @cdeneuve in that case, using an abstract class has an advantage, since you can make the abstract methods protected, so they can be overridden by the concrete sub-classes, but cannot be accessed directly by unrelated classes. You can also make the `executeOrder` method final to prevent it from being overridden. With the interface version, on the other hand, all the interface methods are public by default, so you cannot restrict access to them.